# aurelia/html repeat.for - redundant elements

Tags: aurelia, repeat

I have the following html (view):

```
<li>
    <b>Institute:</b> Length: ${institutes.length}
    <ul>
        <li repeat.for="el of institutes">
        ${el.institute}: ${el.terminalCount}
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I see the following in the browser:

[image]

As seen, the array ***institutes*** has 2 elements, but in list I see 4 more rows - with empty values.
What is it? How I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a [GistRun](https://gist.run/)? Here's [mine](https://gist.run/?id=ea788cf429a1fb1a7d8ba237897dcb0d) which works as expected.

Comment: what we see is that institutes has a property length which is equal to 2
and that for(el of institutes) produces a sequence of 6 elements.
two of which have properties institute and terminalCount
what is actually in institutes?

Comment: there is an extention for chrome which allows you to inspect what is going on in your aurelia app
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aurelia-inspector/ofemgdknaajmpeoblfdjkenbpcfbdefg
pretty sure you will see that there are something else in institutes.

Comment: It seems there was something wrong with created massive. I have changed source for array data and got correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitly have something else on that array apart from the elements. Otherwise it would be just two LI tags.

If you look @ the [source](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/tree/master/src)
there are number of repeater strategies in aurelia templating. Depending on the type of the object you want to iterate over.

If you are actively developing something with aurelia, I suggest you join the [official aurelia discourse](https://discourse.aurelia.io/)
And the [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss)